# Is there a way to perform full text search on multiple columns on Supabase with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I've tried using many symbols to separate columns; ||, |, &&, & with and without spaces.

For instance

```js
.textSearch("username, title, description", "...");
.textSearch("username|title|description", "...");
```

And nothing has worked :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a SQL function to perform search like this:

```sql
create or replace function search_posts(keyword text)
returns setof posts
as
$func$
select 
  * 
from 
  posts
where 
  to_tsvector(username || ' ' || title || ' ' || description) -- concat columns, but be sure to include a space to separate them!
  @@ to_tsquery(keyword);
$func$
language sql;
```

You can call this function like this:

```js
const {data, error} = await supabase.rpc('search_posts', { keyword: '[YOUR_SEARCH_TERM_HERE]' })
```

You can read more about textSearch [here](https://supabase.io/docs/guides/database/full-text-search#search-multiple-columns)

Comment: Thanks for this. Also if you want to return all the columns of the `posts` table from the `select` statement, you can use `returns setof posts` rather than `returns table([YOUR_TABLE_DEFINITION])`

Comment: does this still work? and can I still add some sql pattern like `await supabase.rpc('search_posts', { keyword: '[YOUR_SEARCH_TERM_HERE]' }).where<likt this?>`?

Comment: @JenuelGanawed It should work just fine, and yes you can add additional where clause using filters in Supabase. https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/using-filters